# service worker not intercepting fetch events reliably

Tags: service-worker

I have a webapp that is implemented with flask and nginx (in docker environment)
I want to add a service worker 
so I read [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PWA/comments/bmsed8/this_is_how_i_install_my_service_worker_using/) how to set the configuration such that the scope is the root directory ('/')

When I start the application I can see that my service worker registers, installed and activated. This happens repeatedly as expected.
**But I have a problem to intercept the fetch commands reliably.**

Using chrome devtools, if I set a breakpoint in the install, wait and continue,
then sometimes, the GET operations are routed to the service worker (I can see the console printout from the fetch event listener in the service worker).
When I get to this state, then all fetch events are intercepted, as expected

But if I remove the breakpoints and run the program normally, the service worker doesn't intercept the fetch events.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34147562/service-worker-is-caching-files-but-fetch-event-is-never-fired) that the scope of the service worker can cause to miss of routing. But in such case the miss is systematic, i.e. the path which is not in the scope is never intercepted

This is not my case, because with certain conditions, my service worker does intercept the fetch calls.

My settings are below.

Thanks,
Avner

```
# the file structure
/usr/src/app/web/
├── V1
│   ├── js
│   │   └── mlj
│   │   └── ...
│   │       ├── main.js
│   ├── ...
├── project
│   ├── sites
│   │   └── ...
│   │   └── views.py
└── sw1.js

------------------------------------------------------------

# the file that registers the service worker 
cat main.js
...
    navigator.serviceWorker.register("../../../sw1.js", {scope: '/'})
        .then(regisration => console.log('SW Registered1'))
        .catch(console.error);

------------------------------------------------------------

# the service worker 
cat sw1.js
const version = 1;

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    console.log ('SW v%s installed at', version, new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
});


self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    console.log ('SW v%s activated at', version, new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
});


self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    console.log ('SW v%s fetched at', version, new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
    if(!navigator.onLine) {
        event.respondWith(new Response('<h1> Offline :( </h1>', {headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}}));
    }
    else {
        console.log (event.request.url);
        event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
    }
});


------------------------------------------------------------

# the route to the service worker in the flask python file
cat web/project/sites/views.py
...
from flask import current_app, send_from_directory
...
@sites_blueprint.route('/sw1.js', methods=['GET'])
def sw():
    # /usr/src/app
    root_dir = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())

    filename = 'sw1.js'

    # /usr/src/app/web
    dir1 = os.path.join(root_dir, 'web')

    return send_from_directory(dir1, filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out [here](https://www.chromium.org/blink/serviceworker/service-worker-faq) that on the Chrome Developer Tools Network tab, if Disable cache is checked, requests will go to the network instead of the Service Worker, i.e. Service Worker does not get a fetch event.

After enabling the cache by unchecking the button *Disable cache* (in *Chrome devtool -> Network -> Disable cache*), fetch events are now intercepted by the service worker.

p.s. Note that using the shortcut to [bypass the cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache), e.g. in Chrome: `Ctrl-F5`, `Shift-F5`, and in Firefox: `Ctrl-F5`, `Ctrl-Shift-R` achieves the same effect as unchecking the button *Disable cache*

Comment: Firefox is really a PITA when debugging workers